# Parsing Xml file using python Error: list index out of range for threshold

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a very large  XML file. I need to display the value stored in each and every tag using python. I am trying to use dom library. Can anyone please help?
XML File Link:  https://code.google.com/p/warai/downloads/detail?name=haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc= minidom.parse('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')

size=doc.getElementsByTagName('size')[0]
print size.firstChild.data

stages=doc.getElementsByTagName('stages')[0]
stagen=stages.getElementsByTagName('_')

for stage in stagen:
    stage_threshold=stage.getElementsByTagName('stage_threshold')[0]
    parent=stage.getElementsByTagName('parent')[0]
    anext=stage.getElementsByTagName('next')[0]

    print stage_threshold.firstChild.data
    print parent.firstChild.data
    print anext.firstChild.data

    trees=stage.getElementsByTagName('trees')[0]
    a=trees.getElementsByTagName('_')
    for k in a:
        b=k.getElementsByTagName('_')[0]
        threshold=b.getElementsByTagName('threshold')[0]
        left_val=b.getElementsByTagName('left_val')[0]
        right_val=b.getElementsByTagName('right_val')[0]
        feature=b.getElementsByTagName('feature')[0]
        tilted=feature.getElementsByTagName('tilted')[0]
        rects=feature.getElementsByTagName('rects')[0]
        m=rects.getElementsByTagName('_')[0]
        n=rects.getElementsByTagName('_')[1]


        print m.firstChild.data
        print n.firstChild.data
        print tilted.firstChild.data
        print threshold.firstChild.data
        print left_val.firstChild.data
        print right_val.firstChild.data
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28024893/edit) and include your code.

Comment: Lutz Horn, I have written the code.I am getting 'list index out of range' error.

Answer (score 0):

Use ElementTree interface, for example [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), but other implementations also exist.

Iterate through all elements recursively using iterators to walk the XML tree:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse("xml.xml").getroot()
def print_value(node):
  if node.text and not node.text.isspace(): 
     print(node.text)
  for child in node: print_value(child)

print_value(root)
```

But if the file is really big, and you cannot load the whole tree into memory, use [`.iterparse()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse). It returns element by element - event "start" and "end" means that parser reached beginning or end of current node. If no events are supplied to iterparse function, only "end" is used.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

it = ET.iterparse("xml.xml")

for event, node in it:
  if node.text and not node.text.isspace():   
     print(node.text)
  node.clear()
```

#### Notes

- You may also print `.tail` of each element.
- If you have really, really massive number of elements, you could consider remembering parent for each node, and using `parent.remove(node)` instead of `node.clear()`.